# Paths in ln with hard links and soft links

Tags: symlink, hard-link, ln

How does the relative paths work in `ln (-s or not)`? For example if I type `ln -s foo bar/banana.txt` what does this mean? What is foo relative to? Because it doesn't seem to be relative to the current path. Also is it different if I remove `-s` or not? I've tested it out and the result doesn't make sense to me, and the man page doesn't seem to explain this. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's different with and without `-s`.

With `-s` in:

```
ln -s path/to/file some/dir/link
```

`path/to/file` is set as the symlink target of `some/dir/link` (or `some/dir/link/file` if `link` was a directory).

A symlink is a special type of file which /contains/ a path (can be any array of non-0 bytes, some systems even allow an empty string) which is the target of the symlink. `ln` sets it to the first argument.

Upon resolving the link (when the link is used later on), the `path/to/file` path will be relative to the directory the `link` is (hard-)linked to (`some/dir` here when `some/dir/link` is accessed via its `some/dir/link` path).

Note that the `path/to/file` doesn't need to exist at the time the `ln` command is run (or ever).

While in:

```
ln path/to/file some/dir/link
```

It's similar to:

```
cp path/to/file some/dir/link
```

The `path/to/file` is relative to  the current working directory of the process running `ln`.

Nothing stops you from creating several (hard-)links to a symlink. For example:

```
$ mkdir -p a b/c b/a
$ ln -s ../a b/L # b/L a symlink to "a"
$ ln b/L b/c/L
```

`b/L` and `b/c/L` are the same file: same inode but linked to two different directories. They are both symlinks with target `../a`. But when `b/L` is resolved, that points to `./a` while when `b/c/L`, that points to `./b/a`.